# Express update JWT in response

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I'm using JWT tokens to authenticate the users in my application. I send my token to the backend in `req.headers.access_token` check if I find the current token in the database and if it's still valid, if yes I update the token (update `expires`) and then go to the current route. this part works like it's supposed to.

my problem is sending back the token to the frontend so that the client can send the next request with the updated token, but everything I tried so far didn't update the header correctly:

```
res.header.access_token = token;
res.setHeader('access_token', token);
```

didn't work.

Somewhere I read I need to also add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` so I added the following in my express setup:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization, access_token');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization, access_token');
        next();
    });
```

but the same problem exists.

**Questions:**

- How can I update the token in the header for the response?
- How do people usually handle multiple requests at once (the problem is, that the second request will come with an invalid token since I just
  updated the old one)

I use `jwt-simple` lib for my jwt

Answer (score 1):

- How can I update the token in the header for the response?

Use [`res.set(field [, value])`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set) (instead of `res.setHeader(field, value);` in **ExpressJS 4.x**. E.g.

```
res.set({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization, access_token',
  'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type, Authorization, access_token'
});
```

- How do people usually handle multiple requests at once (the problem is, that the second request will come with an invalid token since I just updated the old one)

You are handling tokens in wrong manner. You don't have to generate a new token and send back to the user on each request. When you are creating a token, you can give an *expire time* for the token (using [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#usage) NodeJS module).

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var profile = {
  first_name: 'John',
  last_name: 'Doe',
  email: 'john@doe.com',
};
var token = jwt.sign(profile, secret, { expiresInMinutes: 60*5 });
```

When a request reach to the server, you can verify it with [`jwt.verify(token, secretOrPublicKey, [options, callback])`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwt-verify-token-secretorpublickey-options-callback) function. Or since you are using ExpressJS, you can use JWT Express middleware.

```
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
// protect /api routes with JWT
app.use('/api', expressJwt({secret: secret}));
```

Refer to [express-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt#usage) NodeJS module for more options.

---

*Reference*: [Cookies vs Tokens. Getting auth right with Angular.JS](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/)